# Posting (AJAX) data to another page

Tags: javascript, ajax, snackjs

I am trying out a small JavaScript library, [SnackJS](http://www.snackjs.com/) and am doing pretty well. But I've hit a wall, and can't seem to figure this one out:

Snack:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    snack.ready(function () {
        var parameters = {
            node: document.body,
            event: 'change',
            delegate: function (node) {
                return node.getElementsByClassName("qty")
            }
        }

        snack.listener(parameters, postToOtherPage);

        function postToOtherPage() {
            var options = {
                method: 'post',
                url: '/InlineEditing',
                data: {
                    qty: 5,
                    id: "hi"
                }
            }
        }
    });
</script>
```

My question is, on the change event of an input element, how do I post the id of the element, along with that element's value (qty) to another page?

I did look through the documentation, but I can't quite figure it out.

Comment: I don't know either from the documentation, but as it's a standard event listener you should get the event object as the first argument and the event target as the `this` object - try to `console.log` them.

Comment: Your question is about the event listener, not about `snack.request`, isn't it?

Comment: Ah, I'm not sure to be honest. What I am trying to do is get the value of the quantity textbox that triggered the 'change' event and also get the #id of the textbox that triggered the 'change' event, so I can POST it ajax style to another page. Hope that makes more sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're missing a

```
snack.request(options, callback);
```

call. A part from that, your code looks fine.. what's wrong with it?

### Update

oh, I see you're not retrieving the id from the element.. from the docs: the first argument to event callback is the node which fired the event, so:

```
snack.ready(function () {
    var parameters = {
        node: document.body,
        event: 'change',
        delegate: function (node) {
            return node.getElementsByClassName("qty")
        }
    }

    snack.listener(parameters, postToOtherPage);

    function postToOtherPage(event) {
        var options = {
            method: 'post',
            url: '/InlineEditing',
            data: {
                qty: 5,
                id: this.id
            }
        }
        snack.request(options, function(){
          // do something with response..
        });
    }
});
```

should work fine..

### Update

Nope, sorry, further reading the docs I found out they're using `callback.apply(this, [event])`, as usual.. updated code above.

By the way, I don't see the point in using this kind of micro-libraries instead of well-established libraries such as jQuery/Zepto, since the pros of the micro-libaries in terms of size are not worth IMO the disadvantages.

Consider that "larger" libaries:

- have a lot more features: what about the day you'll decide to extend your application functionality more?
- have a larger community/commercial-based support: books, reference, guides, ...
- are more likely to have already solved problems/issues that are still there in micro libraries. Just think of the hundreds of cross-browser compatibility hacks...

However, this one is just my opinion, just take it as my personal advice.

Comment: I don't know how to get the actual values from the elements that triggered the change event to begin with using SnackJS.

Comment: Oh my, that's easy! Lol. Thank you @redShadow! Btw, would I do something like `node.innerText` to get the value of the qty textbox?

Comment: How the hell you figure that out from those Docs? Those docs seem to be lacking. Or maybe I'm just slow :/

Comment: Thank you so much. This has helped a lot!

Comment: I managed to figure that out thanks to knowledge of many others libraries "they must have done in a similar way.. oh, right, of course they did" :) Anyways, the not-so-clear doc is another reason for which I'd recommend you to use jQuery :)

Comment: Yeah, jQuery is awesome, but I dunno, I guess I just got bored. :-)