# How to pass checkbox values to another page using ajax or javascript

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery, checkbox

I am using below type of checkboxes. I want to use selected items values in another page. 
I am using javascript and ajax.

I want to pass[url] selected checkbox values to another page using ajax ..

kindly do me favour!!!

```
<form>
    <input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Bike">I have a bike
    <br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Car">I have a car
    <br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="cycle">I have a cycle
    <br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="lorry">I have a lorry
    <br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="house">I have a house
    <br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="mobile">I have a mobile
    <br>
    <input type="button" value="what do u have" onClick=function();/>
</form>
```

thanks in advance!

Comment: You have invalid HTML. On almost every line. `<input />` `<br />` and `onClick=""`

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest you add an ID to each of the elements. Then just do a document.getElementbyId for each of them, check if the checkboxes are checked, and if they are, add their values to the "data" array below. (so for example, value1: document.getElementById("cycle").value). This would send by post a variable you can use in your php function ($_POST['value1'])

Please note that you need jquery for the following syntax to work. Also, if you need to do something with the values returned by the php function, you can you use the succes function posted below.

```
function send()
 {

   $.ajax({ url: 'yourfile.php',
             data: {value1: value1, value2: value2...}, //Modify this
             type: 'post',
             success:   function(output) {

                         alert("It worked!"); 
                 var result= eval("(function(){return " + output + ";})()"); 

             }
   });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if you have very less elements.. ie what ever you mentioned in the question then you can write your own code to get the values and pass it to server side by using javascript or jquery .

Use jquery ajax methods to post the data to server.

You can use jquery form also to submit the complete form. http://www.malsup.com/jquery/form/

Answer (score 0):

For starters i'd say you add the value of your checkbox to a variable. 
This js gets your value. If you want to send more info with it, use "this" and acces the attributes in your function.
If you want to send it to onother page I recommend you to look at the POST method. there are several questions about this on stackoverflow already. like this [Posting (AJAX) data to another page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12923218/posting-ajax-data-to-another-page)

```
<html>
<script>
function getvalue(checkbox)
{
    alert(checkbox);
}

</script>

<form> 
<input type="checkbox" onclick="getvalue(this.value)" name="vehicle" value="Bike">I have a bike<br> 
<input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Car">I have a car <br> 
<input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="cycle">I have a cycle<br> 
<input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="lorry">I have a lorry <br> 
<input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="house">I have a house<br> 
<input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="mobile">I have a mobile 
<br> <input type="button" value="what do u have" onClick=function();/> 
</form>
</html>
```

hope this helps a little